# returning a float type from function in c

Tags: c, floating-point

I have this simple code:

```
int main()
{
    float x = foo();
    printf("returned value: %f", x);
    return 0;
}

float foo ()
{
    return 5;
}
```

when i run the code , the output is: *"returned value: -858993472.000000"*

can somebody please explaing to me why does the returned value isnt 5.000000?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the point at which you call the function there is no prototype in scope. This means that the function is assumed to return `int`. Add a prototype before the point where you first call the function.

```
float f(void);
```

Comment: ... or define `foo()` *before* `main()`. @MOP: You should adjust the warning level settings for your compiler; most compilers will have warned about this do not suppress or ignore warnings.  I suggest you also set warnings as errors (GCC: -Wall -Werror, VC++ \W4 \Wx).

Comment: @Clifford: ...and I would want to make that function definition a prototype as well.